# putting 2 divs side by side and another 2 divs below them

Tags: html, css

Four colored boxes represent four divs, and I want to make my output look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  width: 480px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.container div {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.container div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #b97a56;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Always use snippets where the answer warrants it